# Best way to store a global state for a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app in which moderators can manage `meetings` and normal `users` can attend those meetings.

At some point, the admins should be able to "semi-freeze" the app. This is basically setting a period of time (let's call it a "Frozen Period") during which a few things happen:

- as the meetings created before the frozen period starts will be included in a calculation soon, they cannot be `edit`ed during the frozen period.
- moderators can continue to `create` new meetings and `edit` those meetings, as those new meetings won't affect the calculation.
- warnings appear around the site explaining these issues.

In principle I could create a `FrozenPeriod` model, but I don't actually need to store several frozen periods at a time, as they are discarded once they are over.

Therefore, I'm looking for a "global state" type approach. This should still be stored in the database, but maybe without an associated model.

Does this make sense? Do best practices include a way of having a "singleton model" stored in the database, for example?

Comment: `Rails.cache` is a good place to store this type of temporary state. Just make sure you're using something other than file store.

Comment: Thanks, @SergioTulentsev! Does this hold if this frozen period may last up to two weeks, though?

Comment: Depends on your cache backend, does it do unexpected key expirations, etc. :) Just to play it safe, I'd store in a database. `if FrozenPeriod.count > 0; show_warning`. And then, after you're done, just delete all frozen periods, so that the table is empty again.

Comment: The possibilities are endless here.

Comment: Agreed. I would have liked an option of a "singleton model" where rails knows to find the only one. `if FrozenPeriod.active; show_warning`, for example..

Comment: I got you covered `class FrozenPeriod; alias_method :active?, :exists?; end` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create Model to save this settings to, and create only 1 record in migration:

```
class CreateFrozenPeriod < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
    create_table :frozen_periods do |t|
      t.boolean :active
    end
   end
  # create 1 record to store settings to.
  FrozenPeriod.create
end
```

Use this model as a singleton to set and get the value:

```
class FrozenPeriod 
   def self.active?
      FrozenPeriod.first.active
   end

   def self.active= val 
     FrozenPeriod.first.update_column(:active, val)
   end
end
```

You can also use [Rails Settings Cached](https://github.com/huacnlee/rails-settings-cached) which do the same as above for you, and its good for extending models with settings.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it will be good design to have a `FreezePeriod` model with the following attributes:

- start_date
- end_date

You can then write logic to check if there is currently an active freeze period.

Using this approach allows you to keep a history of freeze periods, and you can also schedule freezes in the future.

Comment: Isn't this over-engineering? He clearly doesn't need any of this advanced functionality (history and scheduling).

Comment: It depends on your taste. I'd hardly call a table with 3-4 columns and a dozen of rows over-engineering.

Comment: Well, but it _is_ waaay over-engineered, compared to a single boolean flag he asked.

Comment: That also depends. If a stakeholder comes in and asks "Hey, who set this little bool flag to true"? and you don't know the answer, you might be in trouble :)

Comment: True that, true that :)

Comment: Don't forget the `frozen_by`, `thawed_by`, `authorized_frozen_by`, `authorized_thawed_by`, `authorization_datetime`, `thawed_datetime` fields.